# Read Image shape from powerpoint programmatically

Tags: powerpoint

I have inserted image shape in powerpoint. And try to read it from programmatically.

I am getting it as as Msogroup which contains rectangle and polyline. So how to read the image shape from powerpoint

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be more specific: what do you mean by "read it from"?  What exactly do you want to do?  And please post any code you have written so far, indicate where it's not working as expected.